# setInterval making async ajax function stop working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The problem is that only my first `updateProgress` function runs while `syncDNS` is waiting. All other calls made through `setInterval` keep waiting until `syncDNS` is finished. Why is that?

```js
$("#syncDNS").click(function() {
  $('#status').html("");
  $('#status').addClass('loading');

  function updateProgress() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'index.php?action=checkProgress',
      datatype: 'text',
      async: 'true',
      success: function(data) {
        $('#status').html(data);
      }
    });
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?action=sync',
    async: 'true',
    success: function(response) {
      clearInterval(loop);
      $('#status').removeClass('loading');
      if (response) {
        $('#status').addClass('alert alert-warning').html("<h4>Aviso</h4>" + response);
      } else {
        $('#status').addClass('alert alert-success').html("<h4>Sucesso</h4>" + "DNS sincronizado com sucesso!");
      }
    }
  });

  updateProgress();

  var loop = setInterval(function() {
    updateProgress();
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Given that you start a new interval every time you trigger a click event on the element I would assume that you're flooding your server with requests, and the delay is a result of that. You can check this in the network tab of the console. This is why AJAX polling is *really* bad practice. If you want to keep the UI and server side data in close sync, use Websockets.

Comment: And do you need to make both calls over and over again?

Comment: Sure, but in this case I only click in the button one time and wait for the answer.

Comment: I only run syncDNS one time, then I run updateProgress every second to get an updated value of how many entries syncDNS has treated.

Comment: Look at your network traffic to determine how long each request takes, and how many are being queued.

Comment: syncDNS takes 11s, and each updateProgress runs in some milliseconds. In a 11s call 11 updateProgress are queued.

Comment: `setTimeout` would be preferred to `setInterval` for this use case, to provide you with better control of the sending of requests.

Answer (score 0):

Remove clearInterval(loop); then it will work again and again.

```
  $.ajax({
  url: 'index.php?action=sync',
  async: 'true',
  success: function(response) {
    //clearInterval(loop);
    $('#status').removeClass('loading');
    if (response) {
     $('#status').addClass('alert alert-warning').html("<h4>Aviso</h4>" + response);
    } else {
    $('#status').addClass('alert alert-success').html("<h4>Sucesso</h4>" + "DNS 
      sincronizado com sucesso!");
    }
   }
  });
```